# Extracting inner data from xml

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I have xml data in following format:

```
<coll>
    <item>
        <key>description</key>
        <value>one</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>name</key>
        <value>John</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>lastName</key>
        <value>Peter</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>institutionCode</key>
        <value>cliente_test</value>
    </item>
</coll>
```

I am converting it to json using following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

This gives me json value:

```
{
  "coll": {
    "item": [
      {
        "key": "description",
        "value": "one"
      },
      {
        "key": "name",
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "key": "lastName",
        "value": "Peter"
      },
      {
        "key": "institutionCode",
        "value": "cliente_test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get json in following format from above xml:

```
{
    "description" : "one",
    "name" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Peter",
    "institutionCode" : "cliente_test"
}
```

Or into following c# object:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("institutionCode")]
    public string InstitutionCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer is: **yes, there is a way**. Please show us what have you already tried and where your *particular* issue is.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: "Is there a way to get json in following format". Yep, of course there is, but it involves you writing some code to transform it to your custom format. There maybe mapping tools around which could help, perhaps - have you done any research? What have you done so far to try and address your goal? TBH I'm surprised at someone with your rep score asking such a poor question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var dict = xDoc.Descendants("item").ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Element("key"), 
                                                 x => (string)x.Element("value"));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

OR

```
var data = JObject.FromObject(dict).ToObject<Data>();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the XML is a collection of item-values. That is why it gets converted to a list in json. There is no other way than implementing it yourself, however it is not a hard task to do. you can just read data into a dictionary and then convert it to json.
Do something like this

```
xmldoc.Load(xmlfile);
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

dynamic node= new ExpandoObject();
var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)node;
    for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
    {
dictionary.Add(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText, xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText)

}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
```